# How should I use sidekiq workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have application in which I can create invoice, render it to pdf and send to the customer. I have two action in my mailer:

```
class InvoiceMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def send_invoice_reminder(invoice)
    @invoice = invoice
    attach_invoice
    mail :subject => "Invoice reminder", :to => invoice.customer.email
  end

  def send_invoice(invoice)
    @invoice = invoice
    attach_invoice
    mail :subject => "Your Invoice", :to => invoice.customer.email
  end

  protected
  def attach_invoice
    attachments["invoice.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      render_to_string(:pdf => "invoice",:template => 'admin/invoices/show.pdf.erb')
    )
  end
end
```

Now I want to send this through Sidkiq workers. But I have question. Whether I need two sidekiq workers:

- one to send invoice email
- second to send reminder

or maybe one worker will be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use one worker for it, because you have mostly the same job for these two tasks

and It can looks like:

```
class InvoiceMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def send_invoice(invoice, subject)
    @invoice = invoice
    attachments["invoice.pdf"] = pdf
    mail subject: subject, to: invoice.customer.email
  end

  private

  def pdf
    WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string render_to_string(
        pdf: "invoice",
        template: 'admin/invoices/show.pdf.erb'
    )
  end
end

class InvoceEmailSender
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(invoice, subject)
    InvoiceMailer.send_invoice(invoice, subject).deliver
  end
end

InvoiceEmailSender.perform_async invoice, 'Your Invoice'
InvoiceEmailSender.perform_async invoice, 'Invoice Reminder'
```